# calling new form by clicking an item in the combobox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a program in C# using `visual studio 2010`.
I have a combobox with different items example

1. X
2. Y
3. Z

I want to call a new form for each selected item.The form will be different for each item.
Kindly tell me how I can do this.

Its a `window application`.

Answer (score 2):

In WinForm try

- [`ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx): Occurs when the SelectedIndex property has changed

  or
- [`ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted): Occurs when the selected item has changed and that change is displayed in the ComboBox

events.

Check Combobox's by these members:

- [`ComboBox.SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext): Gets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a ComboBox.
- [`ComboBox.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem): Gets currently selected item in the ComboBox.
- [`ComboBox.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex): Gets the index specifying the currently selected item.

example:

```
//private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
//or
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox) sender;

    Form1 form = new Form1();
    // You can check senderComboBox.SelectedText or other here
    form.Text = senderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
            if (senderComboBox.(............what should i write here??) ==("celcius-fahrenheit"));
            {

                tempconverter form = new tempconverter();
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
            }

Answer (score 0):

you can register the `SelectedValueChanged` event, and create event handler that will check what is the selected value.
you can add conditional code (e.g. if/else or switch case) that will check what is the form you like to open according to the currently selected value.

sample:

```
    private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I assumed you're working on windows applications (you wrote "software" and not web application).

please take a look at this link to get more details about `SelectedValueChanged` event handler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx

also, many of the controls have various events you can use to take actions according to the user input.

Comment: i tried selectedvaluechanged but this worked only with if statement and when i write else if statement,i get the message "else if not declared in this context"